# Spark Streaming: cannot collect() a DStream when running in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a strange issue when running code via the PySpark bindings to Spark 1.3.1.

Consider the code below:

```
sc = SparkContext("local[1]")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)

myStream = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 4663)

def f(rdd):
    rows = rdd.collect()
    for r in rows:
        print r

myStream.foreachRDD(f)

ssc.start()             
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Now if I run the code above and connect via `nc -lk 4663`, the text I type is printed out on the console of the machine running Spark.  Great.

**However**, if I make a single change to the first line of the code: `sc = SparkContext()` (which will cause it to launch in cluster mode with the driver running on the local machine), my text does not get printed to the console - though I can see messages like

> INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block input-0-1447438549400

being printed to the console, so I know it is still picking up the text that is coming in over the TCP port.

This is odd, because the `collect()` action should force the RDDs in the DStream to be returned to the driver, so I think I should see the text.

Can anyone help me here?  What am I doing wrong?

With many thanks,

Will

Answer (score 0):

If by cluster mode you mean submitting your code using `--deploy-mode cluster`, the driver is not running on the master machine, but on one of the workers.

[Check the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) for more details.

Comment: Hi @marius-soutier , thank you for your response.  I didn't explain myself clearly.  In the second instance I am submitting the job without using the `--deploy-mode` argument.  The documentation says this should default to launching the job in _client mode_.  As I understand it the driver should run on localhost and the job federated out to the slave nodes across the cluster.  That's why I expect `collect()` followed by `print` to show output on the console.